# Are there future plans for the legacy network?

Tags: token

From [The Chrysalis Token Migration Starts Now! publication](https://blog.iota.org/the-chrysalis-token-migration-starts-now/) we can read the following:

> That means that after April 28th, users still holding tokens in the
> legacy network will only be able to send tokens to the migration
> address using Firefly but will no longer be able to send tokens to any
> other addresses in the legacy network (e.g. for payments, addresses
> maintained by exchanges, etc).

So, what will be the utility of the network in the coming months? Is the network shutdown or some similar situation planned? Are IOTA channels still work on this network?

Sorry if this information was published by IOTA, but I haven't found anything related to the above in their posts.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legacy network will be kept alive at least until Coordicide, to make it possible for users to migrate their tokens. All the hardware Ledger users had no chance to migrate their tokens with a "non-beta" wallet so far, and some users might not migrate them right away.

However, you can expect the number of nodes to go down quickly, so while you can still send data transactions fine, the performance and reliability may not be the best. So, I would not expect any service level of the legacy network (I assume that if it goes down it has not highest priority to get up again) and instead migrate all your applications to the new Chrysalis network.